# On click, click something else, prevent default. How do I do this properly with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

What I want to happen is, when you click a link (id="dontFollow"), it triggers a click on a different link(id="follow") and stops you from following the original link.

This is how I thought it should be done-

```
$("#dontFollow").click(function(e){
   $("#follow").click();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

... but it's not working. Whats wrong with my code?

UPDATE:
This is a little more tricky than I originally explained. It appears that I need to "click" on the other link to trigger some other events to cause my page to slide to the anchor. Your suggestions for "window.location" does change the window location but it's not triggering my slide events.

Comment: You haven't stated what isn't working. Your use of `e.preventDefault()` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#dontFollow").click(function(){
   window.open($("#follow").attr('href'));
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

just `return false`

Answer (score 1):

Simply have the function `return false;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can "click a link" programmatically, you can however navigate by setting window.location.href

```
$('#dontFollow').attr('href','#').click(function(){
  window.location.href = $('#follow').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: I have struggled profusely to get a click on a link (<a href="...) to work, useful for when you want to specify a target="_blank" and have it work consistently and cross platform, in the end I gave up on it

Comment: i think you need to give your link an ID. For example $("#link1").click();

Comment: if what you say is true Dave then you might have made my day, sir :) Thanks

Comment: how the crap is it working for me. let me look. Shoot me your code if u want.

Comment: if( 2 > 1 ){$("#rightbutton").click();} HTML...<a id="rightbutton" href=""></a>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Using [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) will prevent you from following the link being clicked.

You have't stated what specifically isn't working, but if you're trying to visit the href of the other link, then do this:

```
$("#dontFollow").click(function(e){
   window.location = $("#follow").attr('href');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```